# Creating static, nested associative arrays in Java

Tags: java, nested, associative-array

I have a data model that I would like to represent in Java as a class, defined by a nested associative array.  I want to be able to create an instance of this object and either reference the key-value pairs by name, or iterate over them.  If I were going to do this in Python or JavaScript, this nested associative array might look something like this:

```
sandwiches = {
    "Ham Sandwich": {
        "bread": "white",
        "meat": "ham",
        "condiment": "mustard"
    },
    "BLT": {
        "bread": "rye",
        "meat": "bacon",
        "condiment": "mayo"
    },
    ...
}
```

Is there a quick and easy way to create an object like this in Java?  I assume that a nested `HashMap` is what I am looking for, but there does not seem to be a simple one- or two-lined method for creating an object like this using the native Java libraries.  If there does not exist a way to do this with the standard Java libraries, what 3rd-party tools would be ideal for this?

Comment: You're going to have to go through the full process pf creating the Maps themselves and adding them to other Maps. Or you can write a String and use a JSON parser to generate the object for you (you'll need a custom type for that too).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Using a JSON parser occurred to me, but it strikes me as odd that there is not a native way to handle this in Java.

Comment: Java requires Types. It can't just assume what you need as the object structure.

Comment: Maybe you mix that up with JavaScript that uses the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) to represent objects. So you will definitely need to parse the JSON data within Java.

Comment: So if I were to go the JSON route, what's the best way to digest the string in my example into a `HashMap`?